# Using clause causing database compatibility mode error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use query with "Join" operator and "Using" clause to avoid using "Natural Join" but somehow I am getting all the time the following error:

> "sID" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a
>   parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function,
>   ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Query what I used is:

```
select sName, GPA
from Student join Apply using (sID)
where sizeHS < 1000 and major = 'CS' and cName = 'Stanford';
```

The column which both Tabels contains is "sID".

The compatibility was changed on 90/100/110 but non of them fixed my problem. To make sure that I correctly changed the compatibility mode I used:

```
SELECT compatibility_level 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'databasePath'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `using (sID)` on `oracle` not for `sql server`. For `sql server` you have to use joins this way

```
select sName, GPA
from Student 
join Apply on Apply.sID = Student.sID 
where sizeHS < 1000 and major = 'CS' and cName = 'Stanford';
```

Comment: `Apply.sID=Student.sID` not `Apply.sID and Student.sID`

Comment: Interesting...instructor in sql course video what I am just learning from used that without mentioning that it's not ms-sql compatible...I know that it's bit off topic but is there a site/sites where I can check if certain operator is compatible with the database I am using?

Comment: @Gizzy I didn't see such sites.

Comment: @Gizzy I'm glad I could help you. I recommended you to read documentation - this is the best source of knowledge.